# Left over array when trying to custom flatmap es2017 Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am getting a left over array when trying to use reduce and concat to implement a custom flatmap.  I have to use use the reduce concat combo as flatmap does not work in es2017 as i am required to use es2017.

my code:

```
function flat(object) {
    return Object
        .entries(object)
        .reduce((acc,[k, v]) => acc.concat([k, ...v.map((s) => `${s} ${k}`)]));
}

var data = { message: { arctic: [], atlantic: ["north", "south"], indian: [], pacific: ["north", "south"], southern: [] } },
    result = { message: flat(data.message) };

console.log(result);
```

my results:

```
{
message:(10) [
"arctic",
 [],
"atlantic",
"north atlantic",
"south atlantic",
"indian",
"pacific",
"north pacific",
"south pacific",
"southern"
]
}
```

What I need:

```
{
message:(9) [
"arctic",
"atlantic",
"north atlantic",
"south atlantic",
"indian",
"pacific",
"north pacific",
"south pacific",
"southern"
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an initial value of an empty array to `reduce`, else the first value of the `acc` in the reduce will be the first entry of the object (and the first entry of the object is `['arctic', []]`. But you want *all* key-value pairs to have the mapping logic (of concatenating the key, and then concatenating any values the key's array may have) applied to them, you don't want to exclude the first item:

```js
function flat(object) {
  return Object
    .entries(object)
    .reduce((acc, [k, v]) => acc.concat([k, ...v.map((s) => `${s} ${k}`)]), []);
    //  --------------------------->                                        ^^
}

var data = {
    message: {
      arctic: [],
      atlantic: ["north", "south"],
      indian: [],
      pacific: ["north", "south"],
      southern: []
    }
  },
  result = {
    message: flat(data.message)
  };

console.log(result);
```